# facebook connect and user email

Tags: facebook

I am developing my site and an important part of it is facebook connect integration. I notice that the fetched emails of users are proxied such as: `apps+32182559871.557007476.0962e412d7b1f0c2027aa51b1141c@proxymail.facebook.com`
Now what can I do with this? Is it possible to send emails by using this address? Sending/tracking user emails is a critical part of my site. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as straightforward as you might think, you need to get permission for your site's app to access the user's email first!

here're a couple of resources you should start with!

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Communicating_with_Users_via_Email

all the best!